# placing two divs side by side. One div has an iframe

Tags: html, css

Probably redundant question. But I am somehow strugling with this.

```
<div class='asset_list_wrapper'>
    <div id='asset_list'>
    </div>
    <div id='asset_view'>
        <iframe src='' frameborder='0' id='mainFrame' name='mainFrame' height='100%' width='100%'></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

.asset_list_wrapper div, iframe {
    float: left;
}
.asset_list_wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
}

.asset_list {
    display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
}
.asset_view{
    display:inline-block;
}

#mainFrame{
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
}

.asset_link_p {
  width: 295px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  margin: 5px;
}
.asset_link{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.asset_link:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:blue;
}
```

The asset_list div shall be 300px wide (that is no problem ;-) ) And the asset_view shall be auto width. Both auto height.
And yet when I load stuff into asset_list it goes beyond wrapper height.
Same goes when loading stuff (from links in asset_list) .. So no top data visible.

Comment: First off, in order to reference an element on the page by its `id` you need to prepend the `id` with `#`, not `.`. Because the `asset_list` and `asset_view` both have ids associated to them, not classes.

Comment: Is the purpose to limit the div height to the available screen height and not scale to the data loaded?

Comment: @OysterMaker That could be an explanation ;-) (stupid me..) But altering the . to a # - no change

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish.. Could you maybe enlighten me a little more? @osomanden

Comment: I am trying to create a div with links - and by clicking the link, opening a php file in the iframe. (prefered to not have a iframe)

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting overflow: hidden to be inherited by your divs to limit the height?  It won't you'd need to specify that rule on each applicable container. EDIT:  Style rules won't apply to the iframe content, either.

Comment: @JECarterII So I must set style on the iframe direct - not via css sheet?

Comment: You won't be able to put a style rule in your css that will affect the content loaded into the iframe because it's a separate browser instance.  But, if you put overflow:hidden on #asset_view, the content would be constrained to that wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do too much hard work. As div itself is a block element it will take the whole width. You can change the div's normal behaviour from block element to inline-block element . That's a way.

```
#asset_list,#asset_view{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Another way is to floating left the first child div element.

```
#asset_list{
   float:left;
 }
```

As HTML in CSS I used # tag for Id's. **Try to use classes instead of ID's**

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark here because I'm still not 100% about the preferred outcome. See the snippet.

The `display:inline-block`s are not needed because of the `float`

I removed the `height:100%` on the `#mainFrame` element and now both divs are side-by-side and seem to be staying within the container boundaries.

```css
.asset_list_wrapper div, iframe {
    float: left;
    height:500px;
}

#asset_list {

    width:300px;
    background-color:blue;
}


#mainFrame{
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
}

.asset_link_p {
  width: 295px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  margin: 5px;
}
.asset_link{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.asset_link:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='asset_list_wrapper'>
    <div id='asset_list'>
    <h1>
    hello
    </h1>
    </div>
    <div id='asset_view'>
        <iframe src='' frameborder='0' id='mainFrame' name='mainFrame' height='100%' width='100%'>hello</iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried.And if content in asset_view is beyond the wrappers top.

Comment: So the content inside your asset_view, which is populated by a separate PHP file, is going beyond the wrapper's height?